# php appending array

Tags: php

OK so I have changed my code to look more like what you have all suggested, but the actual append still does not happen. It simply changes the single value in the array to be the new value being passed in instead of an actual append.

```
if(isset($_POST['addtag']) && isset($_POST['tagname']))
{
  if(isset($_POST['tags']))
  {
    $_POST['tags'][] = $_POST['tagname'];
  }
  else
  {
    $_POST['tags'] = array($_POST['tagname']);
  }
}
```

The reason I check to see if the 'tags' variable has been set is because there's no guarantee that it is an array yet so I don't take the chance of using it like one until I initialize it with an array value.

Here's what happens:
1. I visit the page for the first time.
2. I add a tag ('tag1')
3. The page refreshes and reflects that the 'tags' variable has a size of 1 and displays 'tag1'
4. I add another tag ('tag2')
5. The page refreshes and reflects that the 'tags' variable has a size of 1 and displays 'tag2'

I say "refreshes" because this is the only term I know that specifies that the action of the form points to the page it is located on.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: In the future, you should include any error messages your code generates, or a description of what the code does that you didn't expect it to do. It is very hard for us to diagnose "it is not working".

Comment: OK I updated my original post and described the problem more accurately. There are no error messages though.

Comment: @Storm Kiernan: `$_POST` is not persistent between requests. It will only contain the data you send from the HTML page to the server. So if you don't sent a list of tags to the server with every request, `$_POST['tags']` will always be empty. I think you want a session: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: @Felix Kling: You are correct and your suggestion fixed the problem. I changed all my $_POST['tags'] to $_SESSION['tags'] and the append now works properly. However, I don't necessarily want the 'tags' session variable to survive the life of the session. So I will need to tactfully place an unset($_SESSION['tags']); comment somewhere.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Storm Kiernan: You're welcome :) If you want to have form data survive several pages, you have in fact two possibilities: Either use a session or serialize the data and put it into a hidden field. Using a session is more secure and easier.

Comment: @Storm Kiernan: please accept the best answer and upvote the helpful ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regarding your update:**

`$_POST` is not persistent between request. It will only contain values the HTML pages sends to the server. So as long as you don't send a list of every created tag in each request, `$_POST['tags']` will always be empty.

I think what you want is a [**session**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

You also should read about [form handling in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

---

The only thing you have to do is:

```
$appendedTags = $_POST['tags'];
$appendedTags[] = $_POST['tagname'];
```

or if you really want to use `$_POST['tags']` in further processing (which you shouldn't, I think you have a false concept of `$_POST` in your head (because you write in a comment *post out*.... what does this mean?)):

```
$_POST['tags'][] = $_POST['tagname'];
```

Some remarks on your code:

- In PHP, you don't have to initialise the length of an array. You can add as many elements as you want. You can think of it as a list or table.
- Your `for` loop just copies all values from one array to another. You can achieve the same by just assigning the array contained in `$_POST['tags']` to a new variable.
- If you don't specify an index, the next highest index will be chosen for a new value.

You really should read about [arrays in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: When I say 'post out' I mean set the global variable 'tags' to some new value that I will be able to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, arrays are not of fixed size, they auto-expand, so you do not (and cannot) specify its initial length.

```
$appendedTags[$count + 1];
```

Should be:

```
$appendedTags = array();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not how you create an array with a given length:

```
$appendedTags[$count + 1];
```

Instead, create an empty array and append to it:

```
$appendedTags = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
  $appendedTags[] = $curTags[$i];
}

//add the new tag to the end of the appended tags array
$appendedTags[] = $_POST['tagname'];
```

Since your initial intent seems to be to append a tag directly to `$_POST['tags']`, you can do all this in a single step, assuming `$_POST['tags']` is an array:

```
$_POST['tags'][] = $_POST['tagname'];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array you can add a new item to the end of it simply by doing

```
$array[] = $newitem;
```

or in your case

```
$appendedTags[] = $_POST['tagname'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the array append operator

```
<?php
$array = array('orange');
$array[] = 'apple';
$array[] = 'pear';

print_r($array); //array('orange', 'apple', 'pear')
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

All unnecessary.  This will do exactly what you're trying to achieve.

```
if (isset($_POST['addtag'], $_POST['tagname'])) {

    // put the tagname at the end of the tags array
    $_POST['tags'][] = $_POST['tagname'];
}
```

Arrays in PHP are dynamic.  You don't/can't predefine a size.

http://php.net/array

Answer (score 2):

As per Felix Kling's suggestion, I changed the $_POST to $_SESSION and the values now survive across multiple page requests. Thank you much!

Comment: I don't think you should post this as an answer... put you can accept mine ;) I edited it and included the same I wrote int the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider just using PHP's [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't include array size initialization, as all PHP array are dynamically resizable, meaning that if you have an array that has indexes from 0-4, and try to access index 5, you won't end up with a buffer overflow and will receive just a null value. This is also true for variables, if you try to read a variable that doesn't exist, PHP will quickly create it and set it to null, and you will receive a null value.

With that being said, $appendedTags[$count + 1] will actually try to access the value at $appendedTags[$count + 1]. PHP will realize that nothing exists there, create the $appendedTags array with a null value, and create indexes 0 - ($count + 1), all with null values.

The proper way to initialize the array is with $appendedTags = array(), although that itself is not required as long as $appendedTags is null. Then just assign to the array as needed, PHP will generate the rest as you use it.